# Unable to archive the artifacts with build number

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration

I am trying to set dynamic name to the artifacts in each jenkins build.
In the UI I set $BUILD_NUMER as the tar name that should be created by my script.
I see that tar file also after script execution in the workspace.
But I when I mention $(BUILD_NUMBER).tar.gz in the "Archve artifacts" section, it says "unable to locate" in the console logs.

Comment: Please share the relevant pipeline code used for archiving.

Comment: There is no code.This is from jenkins User Interface. There is a section for Archive artifacts

Comment: So in that case use the [Token Macro](https://plugins.jenkins.io/token-macro/) syntax: `${BUILD_NUMBER}.tar.gz` or  just `$BUILD_NUMBER` if you do not want an extension.

Comment: This worked. This is the right answer  ^^. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

archiveArtifacts "${BUILD_NUMBER}.tag.gz"